# Is it possible to add labels using smart commits in Fisheye?

Tags: version-control, label, fisheye, atlassian-fisheye, smart-commits

This seems to imply that it is only possible to change status and not possible to add labels
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/FISHEYE/Using+smart+commits

Is there a workaround or other way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported by the bundled JIRA smart commits plugin - it currently supports transitioning JIRA issues, tracking time, and adding comments.

You could fairly easily implement a custom commit hook plugin to update the issues mentioned in the commit message (have a look at the [dev tutorial](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/FECRUDEV/FishEye+Smart+Commit+Tutorial)).

Otherwise you might want to add a [feature request](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/FE) to allow updating issue fields through smart commits.

Comment: Well there is a feature request but it looks dormant since 2012, I just wondered if anyone had a 3rd party solution